# How to get data from WordPress post object?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get one of my WordPress post info. my code is

```
$xa = get_post( get_the_ID());
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($xa);
echo '</pre>';
```

This code returns like this... http://postimg.org/image/p7pnvsnb3/
How can I get data form that indicated target which is in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the post title

```
echo $xa->post_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `the_title()`  or you can echo `get_the_title()` .

```
echo get_the_title();
```